# Is it possible to make WIFI scanner on android with API level 29+?

Tags: android, wifi

Even with all the permissions granted the startScan() function still returns false. So my question is: is there a way to scan access points on android 29 or higher?

Comment: Please show which permissions you have asked for, at runtime and in the manifest.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was in asking the user for permission. My working code

-Manifest:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>`

-And for asking user for permissions I used **EasyPermissions**:

```
boolean scanWifi(WifiManager wifiManagerToScan) {

    String[] perm = {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE, Manifest.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE};

    if (EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(this, perm)) {

        registerReceiver(wifiReceiver, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
        boolean scanStarted = wifiManagerToScan.startScan();

        if (scanStarted) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Scanning...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        } else {
           Toast.makeText(this, "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }

    }
    else {
        EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(this, "WE REQUIRE THESE PERMISSIONS FOR THE APP TO FUNCTION", 123, perm);
        return false;
    }
}'
```